# bash: perform action (grep) when file changed

Tags: bash, file, monitor

Googled a lot and didnt, susprisingly, find a working solution. Im an engineer, not a programmer. Just need this tool.

So: I have a file "test2.dat" that I want to grep every time it changes.

I dont have inotifywait or when-changed or any similar stuff installed and I dont have the rights to do so (and dont even want to as I would like this script to be working universally).

Any suggestions?

```
What I tried:
LTIME='stat -c %Z test2.dat'

while true    
do
   ATIME='stat -c %Z test2.dat'

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then    
       grep -i "15 RT" test2.dat > test_grep2.txt
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

but that doesn't do basically anything.

Comment: what happens if you remove `-i`?

Comment: Thanks. Actually nothing happens. Even before removing the -i. The script doesnt do anything and this initial success that I mention above must have been accidental.

Comment: @Jewenile: Why do you have the command within single quotes? Are you expecting the command to be run and output to be stored in the variable. The command-substitution syntax in `bash` is to do `$(cmd)`, so `LTIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)` should be the right statement

Comment: I think this is why its doing grep once, its entering the `if clause` since its true, but then you have `LTIME=$ATIME` inside the if  and thats why it is not entering the if clause again since they become equal. To check if this is the case do an `echo` after the `fi`

Comment: Inian: Because I found that somewhere so. I dont know much of bash syntax as Im learning on the way. Not a programmer. Will try to implement your tips. EDIT: Thanks, it works! : )

Comment: @Jewenile: Happy to be of help, you probably confused with an outdated technique involving backticks `` with command inside for command subsitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for command-substitution is wrong. If you are expecting the command to run within the quotes you are wrong.  The [command-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) syntax in bash is to do `$(cmd)`

Also by doing `[[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]` you are doing a literal *string* comparison which will *never* work. Once you store `LTIME=$ATIME` the subsequent comparison of the strings will never be right.

The appropriate syntax for your script should have been,

```
#!/bin/bash

LTIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)

while true    
do
   ATIME=$(stat -c %Z test2.dat)    
   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]
   then    
       grep -i "15 RT" test2.dat > test_grep2.txt
       LTIME="$ATIME"
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

I would recommend using lower-case letters for variable definitions in `bash`, just re-used your template in the example above.